# Django count shared manytomany between objects and count them

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models, called Article and Label. A simplified snippet of them is below:

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True)
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Label, related_name='pieces', blank=True)
```

When viewing a specific article, I would like to display articles which have similar labels to those applied to the article being viewed, ordered by the number of labels that are shared with the article being read (like "similar articles").

I am attempting to perform this operation in the DB but I am struggling to find a queryset which will give me the same functionality as what I have done in Python by pulling all the articles from DB and performing a for-loop on each of them. A non-functioning query attempt of what I am trying to do is below (viewed_article is the article object being viewed):

```
articles = Article.objects.all()\
               .annotate(
                   tags_count=Article.objects.filter(F('viewed_article.labels')
               ).count()).order_by(tags_count)
```

Comment: As a general comment, `null=True` on `CharFields` is [not recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) and a somewhat complicated query to achieve this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Count, IntegerField, Sum, When

current_labels = viewed_article.labels.all()

similar_articles = Article.objects.filter(labels__in=current_labels).distinct()\
    .annotate(
        tag_count=Sum(
            Case(
                When(labels__in=current_labels, then=1), 
                default=0, output_field=IntegerField()
            )
         )
    ).order_by('-tag_count')
```

What is happening is:

1. Fetch all articles that share any labels with the current one. `distinct()` is required to weed out duplicates returned by the underlying `JOIN` query.
2. Annotate each article with conditional expression. Here it checks the article has each of the current article's labels, and adds 1 to the sum if it does. The result is a count of matching labels.
3. Order results by the count of matching labels.

Comment: It does look right, but I keep getting this error 
    Django Version:  1.8.1
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  'SubqueryConstraint' object has no attribute 'lhs'

Comment: That's strange. I tested the query on Django 1.9 and it worked fine. Maybe there is an issue on 1.8. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: That doesn't look like the complete trace... also post the code you are running?

Comment: Could you tell me which part of the trace you'd like? There are thousands of lines that i'd have to clip as they contain confidential strings of data. Alternatively, do you think the whole problem could be fixed by making a query that points at the manytomany through table? I also attempted to update to django 1.9 but some of the libraries we use have import_module which is deprecated after 1.8

Comment: Actually maybe this? /home/sammonsg/.virtualenvs/carpo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py in _contains_aggregate

                            return getattr(obj.lhs, 'contains_aggregate', False) or getattr(obj.rhs, 'contains_aggregate', False)

     ...

▼ Local vars
Variable  Value
obj  

<django.db.models.sql.where.SubqueryConstraint object at 0x7ff6982be0d0>

cls  

<class 'django.db.models.sql.where.WhereNode'>

Comment: I have just tested the code I posted above on Django 1.8 and it works fine. You must be doing something different which is causing the error - can't really help without seeing the actual query that you are running.

Comment: I don't understand either. This helped me a lot anyways and by using your logic I found a way of doing it in the end. Thank you lots for the help